# Google Cloud Dataflow: Writing to BigQuery after GroupByKey causes lag but CoGroupByKey does not. Why?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I found a strange occurrence while running a Google Cloud Dataflow job. After running a GroupByKey transform and then writing each item from the groups to BigQuery using the WriteToBigQuery transform, the writes were around capped around 500-600 records/second:

[image]

I then ran the exact same job and used a CoGroupByKey instead of the GroupByKey and the writes went up to 50000-100000 records/second:

[image]

I’m not sure if the underlying implementation of the GroupByKey causes this delay/lag and am curious as to why this happens. Has anyone experienced this issue?

I am using Apache Beam V2.4.0 in Python.

Answer (score -1):

The [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) is to performs a relational join between two PCollections having the same  key type. The [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) is to collect all of the values associated with each unique key in a collection.